# Flutter windows desktop application compattibility

Tags: windows, dart, flutter-desktop

Can flutter desktop application run on any windows pc irrespective of its properties. I am trying to run flutter desktop application on x86 windows but it shows error "This application can't run on this pc, check with the software publisher".

Can anyone help me how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Flutter [does not support 32-bit Windows as a target](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/37777).